# Is it harder to get a post to rank for a specific keyword if you already have a post which ranks highly for it?

Tags: seo

Say I've written two articles: one on interesting plot twists and another on how to write a plot twist. If the "interesting plot twist" post already ranks quite highly for the keyword 'how to write a plot twist', does it make it less likely that the other post will get a high ranking for that keyword too. Does Google prefer a diversity of domains in its SERPs, meaning that your own posts can block your more relevant posts from rising to the top?

Comment: It is not about keyword and never has been. Ignore the SEO wizzies that tell you it is. It is about whole language and semantic value. Google was designed to be semantic based **because** keyword based search engines were limited. It says so in the original research paper by Brin and Page in 1997/98. Both pages will perform as they should. Just keep writing. To borrow a phrase, *Let go and let Google.* (from "Let go and let God." meaning: do not worry about it - that is Google's job.) Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks, I generally agree with that, but the question is really: should I avoid writing two posts about very similar topics? If doing this means that one post just displaces the other in the SERPs, then there's not much for me to gain from all that writing...

Comment: Nope. Keep writing. It is about users and not about machines. If you think about it, in any industry, writing about a topic means that there will always be overlap. The trick is to make each unique, even if you find yourself repeating what you have written before once, twice, or even more times. SEO, as a topic, is particularly prone to this. I am struggling with overlap now, and the difficult thing is not what we write, but how do we divide it up, link to it, and so on. Eventually, you will come to the same conclusion. You are simply going to have to repeat yourself. It is the nature of it.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated above - this question is actually about strategies for writing about topics.

Yes, keep writing, but.... in a structured way.

Revisit. No web page is fixed in concrete.

Review the existing page. Does it provide an 'overview' of the topic or go into too much detail on too many aspects? Look for paragraphs which you could fill-out and discuss in more detail. These can become second, third, fourth pages. Focus on the key phrase of each page, if it helps you to write a ***tightly*** focussed page of copy.

By constructing topics this way and so writing in a structured way, it leads naturally to pyramids of pages around a single topic. Pyramids of pages are good. They completely play into the semantics thing, create an 'expertise' and best of all - visitors to your website get a great coherent experience which they can explore as much or as little as they like.

Of course, @closetnoc's philosophy of 'just write' is a good one. Just add 'and review' to the end of the statement. *Just write and review*.

Repeated content (with minor tweaks) is adding little value for the visitor...